# What are the sources of popular Camus quotes?

Tags: reference-request, camus, quote, suicide

I'm tracking down sources of Albert Camus quotes (because Goodreads can suck it). Who can add to this list? I'm not allowed to comment on this site.

- "There is but one truly serious philosophical problem, and that is suicide" is the first line of "The Myth of Sisyphus" (1942) and "The struggle itself toward the heights is enough to fill a man's heart. One must imagine Sisyphus happy." is the last line of the same.
- "But in the end one needs more courage to live than to kill himself." This is a rephrase of a line from the very end of "Natural Death" in *A Happy Death* (1972). To quote directly: "Marthe came to see Mersault and said with a sigh: 'Sometimes there are days when you'd like to change places with him [Zagreus]. But sometimes it takes more courage to live than to shoot yourself.' A week later, Mersault boarded a ship for Marseilles."
- "Should I kill myself or have a cup of coffee?" I've read that this is a misquote, from a fake letter: [Did Camus ever really write "Should I kill myself or have a cup of coffee"?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/68513/did-camus-ever-really-write-should-i-kill-myself-or-have-a-cup-of-coffee)
- More? Help me and fellow struggling epigraph writers out! Thanks.

Comment: Which way did you come in?

Comment: See [Albert Camus](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Albert_Camus)

Comment: Re *suicide*, something very similar: [*La Morte heureuse* (1936-1938), published 1971](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Mort_heureuse), Ch.IV: "Mersault répondit seulement : « Oui, je m'ennuie », et après temps se redressa [...] : « J'ai envie de me marier, *de me suicider*, ou de m'abonner à L'Illustration. Un geste désespéré, quoi. » See [here](https://www.google.it/books/edition/La_mort_heureuse/k6_FkgLc7sQC).

Comment: You might find https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Albert_Camus helpful. But I don't know how reliable it is, though it seems to work hard at that.